# Change every character in textbox

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I am having a problem with string replacement. Below is my code as of now. I want to replace each character in textbox1 and write it to textbox2, but this only works for the last character.

If I write:

> Hello

Then it should end up as:

> [[h]][[e]][[l]][[l]][[o]]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Try
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("0"c, "[[something0a0]]")
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("1"c, "[[something1a1]]")
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("2"c, "[[something2a2]]")
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("3"c, "[[something3a3]]")   

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way you could do this is using a loop like this. Not sure if it's the most efficient, but it's fairly easy to understand:

```
TextBox2.Text = ""
For Each chr As Char In TextBox1.Text
    TextBox2.Text += "[[" & chr & "]]"
Next
```

And another simple way is:

```
TextBox2.Text = "[[" & String.Join("]][[ ", TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray().AsEnumerable()) & "]]"
```

HTH

Comment: No prob. So did it answer your question?

Comment: @AlešKalan, If it answers your question, then could you please mark it as so? It will help other users and people with similar questions know that this question's answered

Comment: @AlešKalan, just so you know, to mark something as answer, you select the green check next to the answer that solved your problem. You don't put [solved] in the title.

Answer (score 4):

You're overwriting the value of `TextBox2`. Chain your `Replace` calls instead and set the assignment once.

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("0"c, "[[something0a0]]")
                             .Replace("1"c, "[[something1a1]]")
                             .Replace("2"c, "[[something2a2]]")
                             .Replace("3"c, "[[something3a3]]")
```